# Express session cookies are not being set if domain is not localhost

Tags: express, cookies, vite, express-session

Im hosting backend express app on cyclic and frontend react (with vite) app on vercel and as title says cookies are not being set. (Session is being set in db though)
(I'm using express session with passport). (I don't use proxy)
Here's session and cors middleware configuration:

```
app.use(cors({ origin: allowedOrigins, credentials: true }));

app.use(session({
   secret: process.env.SECRET,
   resave: false,
   saveUninitialized: true,
   store: MongoStore.create({ mongoUrl: process.env.MONGO_URL, collectionName: "sessions" }),
   cookie: {
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "None",
      httpOnly: false
   }
}));

app.use(cookieParser(process.env.SECRET));


import passportConfig from "./config/passport.js";
passportConfig(passport);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

And example of the request from the client:

```
      const data =  await request.formData();
      const url = import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL + "/log-in";
      const response = await Axios({
         method: "POST",
         data: {
            username: data.get("username"),
            password: data.get("password")
         },
         withCredentials: true,
         url: url
         
      })
```

I've tried to configure session middleware without explicitly setting secure to true, sameSite to "None" and httpOnly to false, i've tried changing platforms where i host my app, nothing works.

Here's the repo with full code https://github.com/yunytsky/passport-local-strategy-mern